# Raspberry hostname change but not really

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, host, hostname

I change hostname in /etc/hosts and also in /etc/hostname

hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1       newhost
```

hostname:

```
newhost
```

Yea it works

```
>>> socket.gethostbyname('newhost')
'10.0.0.45'
```

**BUT**

```
import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('10.0.0.45')
('raspberrypi', [], ['10.0.0.45'])
```

Sometime ago I used different name and it work both way, then I changed it and it keeps showing me raspberrypi. I believe there must be some default file that triggers this. Anyone? **Thanks in advance guys**

Comment: Use `sudo raspi-config` to change hostname thoroughly.

Comment: not helpful or relevant. I know how to change hostname, but I dont know why pi still shows on the network as 'raspberrypi' even though I can find the pi with socket.gethostbyname('newhost')

Answer (score 1):

raspi-config does not appear to be well documented but the solution to changing the hostname is

```
sudo raspi-config nonint do_hostname ${NEW_HOSTNAME}
sudo reboot # Must reboot to see change
```

This is since raspi-config is a bash script and has a noninteractive mode you can use. Of which as of now, this is what we are trying to trigger below:

```
do_hostname() {
  if [ "$INTERACTIVE" = True ]; then
    whiptail --msgbox "\
Please note: RFCs mandate that a hostname's labels \
may contain only the ASCII letters 'a' through 'z' (case-insensitive), 
the digits '0' through '9', and the hyphen.
Hostname labels cannot begin or end with a hyphen. 
No other symbols, punctuation characters, or blank spaces are permitted.\
" 20 70 1
  fi
  CURRENT_HOSTNAME=`cat /etc/hostname | tr -d " \t\n\r"`
  if [ "$INTERACTIVE" = True ]; then
    NEW_HOSTNAME=$(whiptail --inputbox "Please enter a hostname" 20 60 "$CURRENT_HOSTNAME" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
  else
    NEW_HOSTNAME=$1
    true
  fi
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $NEW_HOSTNAME > /etc/hostname
    sed -i "s/127.0.1.1.*$CURRENT_HOSTNAME/127.0.1.1\t$NEW_HOSTNAME/g" /etc/hosts
    ASK_TO_REBOOT=1
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[SOLVED]**

Building upon MichielB's answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/114400/how-to-set-the-hostname-via-boot-config-before-first-boot/145338#145338), the code for changing it dynamically through a new_hostname file after the pi has been set up is here, **no modification to the command line is necessary and you will have NOT have to reboot the pi after its done**. This code is for the situation where you wanna mass produce an OS image from a base image and your greater shell script modifies the hostname file to create its own unique OS image, thus the whole hostname changing process is automated and no reboot is necessary. The code can be used with custom front-end services to change the hostname dynamically

More details in the github link:
https://github.com/techscapades/change-raspberrypi-hostname-from-file-no-reboot

```
#!/bin/bash

set +e

CURRENT_HOSTNAME=`cat /etc/hostname | tr -d " \t\n\r"`
NEW_HOSTNAME=`cat /path_to_new_hostname_file | tr -d " \t\n\r"`

echo `cat /path_to_new_hostname_file | tr -d "\t\n\r"` >/etc/hostname
sed -i "s/127.0.1.1.*$CURRENT_HOSTNAME/127.0.1.1\t$NEW_HOSTNAME/g" /etc/hosts
echo `cat /etc/new_hostname | tr -d "\t\n\r"` >/proc/sys/kernel/hostname

exit 0
```

you can throw in `systemctl restart avahi-daemon` before it exits but you might have to wait a while before you can access your_new_hostname.local again

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct in saying you just want to change the hostname of the pi, and you're running raspbian, then there should be an option in raspberry pi configuration to change it

Comment: 1. I don't want to do it like this. 2. New host name is already in raspi-config  so it doesn't help

Comment: I already changed hostname, but on the network its still visible as 'raspberrypi' yet I can find it even with the new hostname. I just want one hostname. I want 'raspberrypi' to be totally anihilated as hostname. -> Thats what is the question about. Why the raspberrypi host name still persist the change

Comment: Are you using the latest version of raspbian?